# Safely delete from boost::interprocess::vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, boost-interprocess

**Types:**

```
namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;

typedef bipc::allocator<char, bipc::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> char_allocator; 
typedef bipc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, char_allocator> shmem_string; 

typedef bipc::allocator<shmem_string, bipc::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> string_allocator;
typedef bipc::vector<shmem_string, string_allocator> shmem_vector;
```

**Current usage:**

```
le_buffer = shmem.construct<shmem_vector>("le_buffer")(some_string_allocator);
le_buffer->push_back(some_shmem_string);
```

**Trouble:**

Now I need to iterate over this vector and delete all strings that parsed as int are equal 123.

```
int size = le_buffer->size();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   int tmp = parse(le_buffer->at(i));
   if(tmp == 123) {
    // ???
   }
}
```

how to safely delete those strings from `le_buffer`?

Comment: Not familiar with boost interprocess vector but any chance it is usable with std::remove_if ?